# Issue with polymer layout and "position: fixed"

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position, polymer

I am currently learning polymer and encountered the following problem:

I'd like to have a split layout where the left side is a list of items and the right side can display additional information about the selected item.

I tried to achieve this with the following (simplified) code:

```
<body fullbleed vertical layout>

  <style type="text/css">
    .card_container {
      margin: 16px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .details_container {
/*    position: fixed;
*/ }
    .white-bg {
      background-color: white;
      margin: 8px;
      max-width: 650px;
    }
    .white-bg.details {
      margin: 24px 24px;
    }
  </style>

  <div layout horizontal center-justified>
    <div id="card_container" class="card_container" layout vertical>
      <div class="white-bg">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="white-bg">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="white-bg">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="white-bg">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="details_container" layout vertical flex>
      <div class="white-bg details" flex relative>
        <p>Some sample text...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

The layout looks quite nice, until I assign `position: fixed` to the `details_container` div.

I created a JSBin that demonstrates the problem: http://jsbin.com/ziqayufojeco/2/edit?html,output
Just uncomment the `position: fixed;` attribute.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Facing same issue..! try to add `fixed` in `iron-pages` but it is not working in any way... :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know what the specifications say, but I'm not surprised that you cannot use `flex` in combination with `position: fixed`.

The `flex` attribute (which is shorthand for CSS flex properties) tells CSS how to position and size a element relative to it's sibling elements. OTOH, `position: fixed` tells CSS that you want the element to be very specifically positioned.

I can understand that you would like the calculated size to be the same regardless of `position: fixed`, but it doesn't work that way. I'd like to suggest an alternative, but I can't figure out what outcome you were after.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why `postion: fixed` is not working in `polymer starter app` element.

But to adding fixed element functinality you can use `postion: sticky` with `display:flex`